# How to explain this?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is bounded from above by $N$. Show that if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) =L$, then $L \leq N$.

Comment: $L \leq N$ is true but $L <N$ is false.

Comment: Assume that $L>N$ and show that $|f(x)-L|$ does not tend to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The way I prefer is as follows.

- Show that you can find a sequence $(x_n) \to c$ such that the sequence $(f(x_n)) \to L$.
- Show that each $f(x_n) \leq N$.
- Use the fact that weak inequality is preserved in the limit of sequences.

The reason I prefer this is because it's very concrete; sequences are much more intuitive objects than functions are.